# Where does bbPress store author info for anonymous users?

Tags: bbpress

I have WordPress and bbPress installed. All is working fine, except that when I need to do a custom query, I don't know which fields in the database to reference for topics created by *anonymous* users.

Usually, using `wp_insert_post`, we would use something like `post_author` and use the ID of the person creating the post, but without the ID, we cannot do much.

Any pointers?

Comment: I found the answer. Basically it stores them as meta data to the post ( added using  **wp_update_meta**   )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Basically it stores them as meta data to the post (added using `wp_update_meta`).

It stores them as:

```
_bbp_anonymous_name
_bbp_anonymous_email
_bbp_anonymous_website 
_bbp_last_active_time
```